# tune2fs -l /dev/nvme0n1p1, Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock

Tags: partition, disk, fsck

I'm following https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelSuspend to debug a kernel suspend bug. There's a section which asks me to get the current fsck settings for a partition. I **think** my partition is `/dev/nvme0n1p1` so I tried:

```
[lz@dom0 ~]$ df -h
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                     2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs                        2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                        2.0G  1.4M  2.0G   1% /run
tmpfs                        2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/qubes_dom0-root  445G  5.2G  417G   2% /
tmpfs                        2.0G  8.0K  2.0G   1% /tmp
xenstore                     2.0G  232K  2.0G   1% /var/lib/xenstored
/dev/nvme0n1p1               500M   61M  440M  13% /boot/efi
tmpfs                        393M  8.0K  393M   1% /run/user/1000
[lz@dom0 ~]$ tune2fs -l /dev/nvme0n1p1
tune2fs 1.43.3 (04-Sep-2016)
tune2fs: Permission denied while trying to open /dev/nvme0n1p1
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

What am I doing wrong? Isn't this the partition? THe other ones looks virtual to me, /dev/nvme0n1p1 looks like is the only 'real' one

Answer (score 2):

First, you'll need to prefix `tune2fs` with `sudo`. But read on...

Your `/dev/nvme0n1p1` is `/boot/efi` which is the common mountpoint for the EFI System Partition that contains UEFI bootloader(s). Usually it contains a FAT32 filesystem, since that is the only filesystem type guaranteed to be supported by the UEFI firmware specification. The `tune2fs` command only works for `ext2`, `ext3` and `ext4` filesystem types, not for FAT32.

Your `/dev/mapper/qubes_dom0-root` could be a LVM logical volume. It is a device handled by the device-mapper subsystem, but it is not necessarily any less "real" than any partition device. The mapping between the blocks of that device and of actual disk device is just a bit more flexible and can refer to more than one physical disk or partition. But virtual or not, that's where your root filesystem resides - and if you need to manipulate that filesystem with `tune2fs`, that's the correct target device for the command.

Comment: thanks you. So, tuns2fs works there. However, `tune2fs` was meant to be used to check the "Check interval" value. It's 0 for my system, which is not possible. This value means the interval for which the system should check for fsck on boot, something like that. It was supposed to be a large value. Anyways, I rebooted and got what I think was a large fsck, because it took 1h to boot (Qubes only shows a progress bar, don't show what's happening)

Comment: I think I was not clear. I should set the value to 0 with `'tune2fs -i 0 partition` , but the value is already 0 (on /dev/nvme0n1p1). However, when I reboot, I still get an fsck, which should not happen for a value 0 (or what I think is an fsck, because it takes too much)